# postgresql embedded function return

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I'm trying to call a function from a trigger function and don't understand what control structure to use.  Here's the situation:
I have 3 tables (table1, table2, table3) and two functions (Fct1 and Fct2).
Fct1 is a trigger function triggered after an insert in table1 and which makes insert in table2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fct1()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

TRUNCATE "table2";
INSERT INTO "table2"
SELECT  ... FROM "table1";

RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

The trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_fct1
    AFTER INSERT
    ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ((pg_trigger_depth() < 1))
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE Fct1();
```

If I do after that a `SELECT "Fct2"();` everything works fine, but if I add in Fct1 a `PERFORM "Fct2"();` , like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fct1()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

TRUNCATE "table2";
INSERT INTO "table2"
SELECT  ... FROM "table1";

TRUNCATE "table3";
PERFORM "Fct2"(); -- will insert into table3

RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

It takes much more time to run (I never waited for the end, it's too long).
Fct2 looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Fct2"()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

INSERT INTO "table3" ...;

RETURN;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

So, there is something I don't understand and I think it is related to these 'RETURNs' which are not clear to me.  I have tried different 'solutions' but I always got errors mentioning some 'return' mismatches.  Any suggestions  ?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create trigger` statement that you used (is that a row level trigger or a statement level trigger)?

Comment: 'create trigger' statement added.

Comment: Finally I re-wrote my function and changed the trigger to 'For each statement' which was the right way to do it.  Besides the fact that my code was very badly written (quick and dirty) there was some sort of loop due to the 'for each row' and the processing time was exponential with the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

To capture long running SQL statements from functions in the log, you can use [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) with `auto_explain.log_nested_statements` set to `on`. But if the query doesn't even finish, that won't help a lot.

My bet is that you are blocked by a database lock. Set `log_lock_waits` to `on` and see if something is reported in the log. You should also query [`pg_locks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-locks.html) to see if there are locks requested but not granted.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz for taking the time to answer.  I finally totally rewrote my function and trigger and it works very welle now.